# Vim unhides hidden files on Windows

Tags: windows, vim

I've noticed that Vim (gVim on Windows 8) unhides hidden files.

By hidden files I don't mean dotfiles; in Windows we don't have dotfiles. It appears that the 'hidden' file attribute on the file is being removed.

Any suggestions/workarounds?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you mean vim is unsetting the hidden attribute on the files? (e.g. `attrib -h`)

Comment: Certain [tag:vim] questions are on-toppic for StackOverflow, under the category, ["Software development tools"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @verdammelt Didn't know `attrib` existed, but yes it seems to be resetting it on save. @Jonsyweb thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see this problem on Windows when the `writebackup` option is enabled and `backupcopy` is set to `no` or `auto`. To fix it, add the following line to *.vimrc*:

```
set backupcopy=yes
```

The `writebackup` setting instructs Vim to make a backup before overwriting a file, and `backupcopy` controls how this backup file is created:

> ```
> "yes"   make a copy of the file and overwrite the original one
> "no"    rename the file and write a new one
> "auto"  one of the previous, what works best
> ```

As we can see, when the value of `backupcopy` is set to `no`, Vim will rename  the original file that contains the *hidden* attribute and write a new file in its place *without* that attribute set (and then delete the backup file afterward unless we enable the `backup` option). This is faster but can cause problems with file attributes and symlinks.

For more information, read `:help backupcopy`. We can check the current values of `writebackup` and `backupcopy` by running:

```
:set writebackup? backupcopy?
```

Comment: Incredible, it's been nearly four years since I posted this question. Since then, I have moved from Windows to macOS, and have basically ceased using vim on the command line.

Regardless, this seems like the right answer. Amazing what a bounty can do ;)